# reload form on done function jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to pass an input value to a php session variable.
With the code below, I can send the input value to the session but only appears in the alert box or if I refresh the page, which I do not want.
I added the line `$ ("# form1") [0] .reset ();` to refresh the form and thus have the value of the session printed on the screen, but it is not working.

index.php:

```php
<?php
    @session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    ?>
  <!doctype html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>input value to php session</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="post" id="form1">
      <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" onblur="run(this)">
    </form>
    <br /><br />
    <?php echo $_SESSION['field1'];?>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
      function run(sel) {
        var text = $("#field1").val();
        if (text != "") {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "input.php",
            data: {
              field1: text
            }
          }); //.done(function() {alert(text)});    
        }

        if (done.(function() {
            $("#form1").reset()
          }));
      }
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

The input.php file:

```
<?php
  @session_start();
  error_reporting(0);

  if (isset($_POST["field1"])){
    $_SESSION['field1'] = $_POST["field1"]; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: I cannot follow what you are attempting to do here. Makes no sense. 1) There is no return data from the input.php, 2) There is no session data in a form field, 3) Resetting a form just resets the form fields back to their starting values only. 4) Whats wrong with the `success:` callback for `.ajax`?

Comment: The syntax is wrong `if (done.(function() {
            $("#form1").reset()
          }));` the commented code should work, if you will reset the `form` there. Read about it in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `<div>` around your value and change it when `.done()`:

To get your session value, you have to `echo` it and use it inside your `done()` callback:

```
<?php
@session_start();
error_reporting(0);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>input value to php session</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" onblur="run(this)">
</form>
<br /><br />

<!-- HERE wrap into a div with an ID -->
<div id="session-field"><?php echo $_SESSION['field1'];?></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function run(sel) {
    var text = $("#field1").val();
    if (text != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "input.php",
            data: { field1: text}
        })
        // done callback using data (wha
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#session-field').html(data);
            $("#field1")[0].form.reset();
        });
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And your input.php:

```
<?php
@session_start();
error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST["field1"])){
   $_SESSION['field1'] = $_POST["field1"];
   echo $_SESSION['field1'] ; // echo outputs
}
?>
```

Comment: Arg. LOL. Beat me to it =D

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simply display the value that was just sent to PHP, you can do it in a couple of ways.

First, you could just put in on the page with JS

```
function run(sel) {
        var text = $("#field1").val();
        $('#some_div').append(text);
        if (text != "") {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "input.php",
            data: {
              field1: text
            }
          }); 
        }
```

Or if you want to be sure it was saved as the `SESSION` variable, you can return it from PHP and then put it on the page with JS

```
<?php
  @session_start();
  error_reporting(0);

  if (isset($_POST["field1"])){
    $_SESSION['field1'] = $_POST["field1"]; 
    echo $_SESSION['field1'];
  }

?>
```

and then in your JS

```
function run(sel) {
       var text = $("#field1").val();
       $('#some_div').append(text);
       if (text != "") {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "input.php",
            data: {
              field1: text
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#some_div').append(data);
            }
          }); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a div to your HTML with id output-session and then print the $_POST["field1"] in input.php so it get's appended to that div.

index.php

```
<script language="javascript">
function run(sel) {
var text = $("#field1").val();
if (text != "") {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "input.php",
        data: { field1: text},
        success: function(msg){

          if (msg != ''){                
          $("#output-session").html(msg);
          }        
        }
    });
}
</script>
<div id="output-session"></div>
```

input.php

```
<?php
@session_start();
error_reporting(0);

if(isset($_POST["field1"])){
$_SESSION['field1'] = $_POST["field1"]; 
print $_POST["field1"];
}
?>
```